# converting .ZIP to .STL

Tags: printing, 3d

I have a 3D printer (prusa i3 MK2) and if I download something online it always comes in as a .ZIP. I don't know how to fix this because every time I rename the file into a file type the printer will recognize, it just doesn't work. how do I get files as a .STL instead of a .ZIP

Comment: Have you tried unzipping it?

Comment: actually i found the answer

Comment: The answer is that you unzipped it. This is very basic computer usage.

Answer (score 0):

So, don't waste your time with converters, just open the .zip file with archive manager and find the file ending in .stl and extract it to the directory of your choice.